# Bitwise setting in C++

Tags: c++, c

```
#define OUTGOING_MASK         0x0c
#define OUTGOING_DISABLED     0x04
#define OUTGOING_ENABLED      0x08
#define OUTGOING_AUTO         0x00
#define REFER_SUPPORTED       0x80
```

Assume `support` is some value of type int.
I have a getter function

```
int get()
{
if(OUTGOING_DISABLED == support & OUTGOING_MASK)
return 1;
else if(OUTGOING_ENABLED == support & OUTGOING_MASK)
return 2;
else if(OUTGOING_AUTO == support & OUTGOING_MASK)
return 3;
}
```

I need to write set function for this like

```
void set(int val)
{
if(val ==1)
//todo
else if(value == 2)
//todo
else if(value == 3)
//todo
}
```

How to write getter and setter functions for this?
I need to get/set the `support` variable here

REFER_SUPPORTED will always be set in `support`.

Comment: b still contains the value of b even after the statement.  What do you want to do with the value of b?  Print the value of b?

Comment: Given a2, and a1 which equals to b & a2, do you want to recover the value of b?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are returning 1,2,3 instead of OUTGOING_DISABLED, OUTGOING_ENABLED and OUTGOING_AUTO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a statement such as a1 = b & a2; How to know the value of b using bitwise operators?

You can't recover value of b, unless a has ALL bits set. "&" is irreversible.

Explanation. & operation has following table:

```
a   b   result
1 & 1 = 1
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
0 & 0 = 0
```

which means, to recover b, you could try to use following table:

```
a   result  b
0   0       unknown - could be 1 or 0
0   1       invalid/impossible - could not happen
1   0       0
1   1       1
```

As you can see it isn't possible to guess b in all cases.

In expression a & b = c, if you know c and a, you can't recover b, because for every zeroed bit of c, and if corresponding bit of a is also zero, there are two possible states of corresponding bits of b. You can reliably recover b only if every bit of a is set to 1.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  In general, you can't recover that info given only `a1` and `a2`.  To see this, consider the case of `a2 == 0`.  `b & 0` is always 0.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. In my code, a2 can never be zero.It will be 3 or 4 generally. In that case, how to do? But a1 can be zero

Comment: You still can't.  `8 & 3` and `4 & 3` are both 0, to give an example.

Answer (score 2):

Is the following what you want:

```
void set(int val)
{
    support &= ~OUTGOING_MASK;
    support |= REFER_SUPPORTED;

    if(val == 1)
    {
        support |= OUTGOING_DISABLED;
    }
    else if(value == 2)
    {
        support |= OUTGOING_ENABLED;
    }
    else if(value == 3)
    {
        support |= OUTGOING_AUTO;
    }
}
```

<strike>If that is the case, then I believe you getter function is also wrong. According to my understanding, it should be as follows:</strike>

```
int get()
{
    if(OUTGOING_DISABLED == ((support & OUTGOING_MASK) >> 2))
        return 1;
    else if(OUTGOING_ENABLED == ((support & OUTGOING_MASK) >> 2))
        return 2;
    else if(OUTGOING_AUTO == ((support & OUTGOING_MASK) >> 2))
        return 3;
}
```

Comment: Yeah...but i have another one called 
#define REFER_SUPPORTED             0x80
which will always be set in support

Comment: Thanks. can you write getter also according to the setter.

Comment: your getter looks alright. i was wrong when i wrote the getter function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code to print out the binary equivalent

```
void printBit(int n)
{
  unsigned int i;
  i = 1<<(sizeof(n) * 8 - 1);

  while (i > 0)
  {
     if (n & i)
     {  
       printf("1");
     }
     else
     { 
        printf("0");
     }
    i >>= 1;
}
}
```

That would simply print out the binary equivalent of 'b'. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: No. I dont want binary equivalent of b. I just want the value of b

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more clear about what you mean by 'value'.